Factorization of a map because composition is $0$
I apologize for the vagueness of the object I'm referring to. This question comes from considering sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules homomorphisms, but I feel that the answer is something more general I am not seeing.
Let us work in an abelian category and let $f: D\to B$ be a map. Suppose that there exists a short exact sequence $$0 \to A\to B\to C\to 0.$$
Is it true that $f$ factors through $A\to B$?
I've encountered several times such a line of reasoning (also considering $g: E\to C$ for instance), which made me believe the answer is some sort of diagram chasing I cannot show.
If you can provide me a reference it would be quite helpful, thanks in advance.

This is certainly not true in general. For instance, let $0 \to \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z/2 \to 0$ be the standard presentation of $\mathbb Z/2$ as an abelian group. The map on the left (call it $g$) is multiplication by $2$; if we take $f$ to be the identity $\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z$, then $f$ does not factor through $g$.

You need to add the assumption that $D\to B\to C$ is zero (which is in your title but not your post), otherwise the example from the comments of $0\to \Bbb Z \stackrel{\cdot 2}{\to} \Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z/2\to 0$ and $id_{\Bbb Z}$ is a counterexample. Once you have this assumption, you can use the universal property of the kernel to conclude that $D\to B$ factors as $D\to A \to B$:
Definition. Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category with zero morphisms. Let $f:X\to Y$ be a morphism in $\mathcal{C}$. The kernel of $f$ is an object $K$ with a morphism $k: K\to X$ such that $f\circ k=0$ and given any morphism $k':K'\to X$ such that $f\circ k'=0$, there exists a unique morphism $u:K'\to K$ so that $k\circ u = k'$. (ref Wikipedia, for instance.)

I see, so I misunderstood their approach. Thank you!
